# JS FileReader not working in safari it is working fine in chrome

Tags: javascript

I have created function to display image
please help on this if you have any alternative solution.

```
admin.previewImage = function(input,selector) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $(selector).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: which version of safari?

Comment: any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari doesn't support for js file reader

So I tried this

https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify

It Works for me

Comment: isn't that for just downloading the file?? if you fix the issue you have mentioned can you please explain how you did?? thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that this is out of date. Safari has supported `FileReader` (*outside* of web workers) since v6.

Answer (score 1):

The file reader is only available in safari 6.0 
and unfortunately we cannot use it as it is.
U can use an external plugin to show the preview of image or check the availability of filereader api in your browser if not found bypass it with any other issue handling strategies

`if(window.FileReader) {   //do this
} else {
   //the browser doesn't support the FileReader Object, so do this
}`

Answer (score 0):

The FileReader API is only available as of Safari 6.0
However, if it's important for you to have this functionality in all browsers, you could test for the availability of the FileReader API:
if(window.FileReader) { //do this} else {//the browser doesn't support the FileReader Object, so do this}